# System language issues

Tags: environment-variables, system, kde-plasma

Either something is very strange, or I am missing something very simple.

First: I am running plasma on top of Debian Bullseye sid.

I have a bit of a complex language setup: default LC_ALL is en_US.UTF-8, as is LC_MONETARY at the moment (I am in USA at the moment). The other LC variables (collate, numeric, time, measurement) are en_150.UTF-8 (that is European English; I am far more used to them and like them more than USAnian ones).

I have several other language packages installed: Russian, Swedish, German, Finnish.

Keyboard is set to US in KDE.

But--here is the weirdness--system messages in bash (and in R, and in PCMANFM, etc) are in Russian, and I see no ru setting anywhere. (The only exception is my LANGUAGE=en_US:en_GB:ru:fi:de:sv--but isn't the first language on the list supposed to be used?)

Any ideas why this may be happening? Is it that the system is confused because of different settings in LC variables? Are there some other env variables of which I am not aware?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by removing all the KDE language packs with the exception of en_US and en_GB. Apparently, it does not really know what the correct language to display is when there are more than one. :(